# Different results for QString to const char*

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, const-char

I have a code snippet to test a code bug.

```
    #include <QCoreApplication>
    #include <QDebug>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
        QString name = QString("Lucy");
        QString interest = QString("Swimming");

        const char* strInterest = interest.toLatin1().data();
        const char* strName = name.toLatin1().data();

        qDebug()<<"QName: "<<name<<" QInterest: "<<interest;
        qDebug()<<"Name: "<<strName<<" Interest: "<<strInterest;

        return a.exec();
    }
```

The result on **macOS**:

`QName:  "Lucy"  QInterest:  "Swimming"
Name:  Lucy  Interest:`
.

The result on **ubuntu**:

`root@:test$ ./testCharP 
QName:  "Lucy"  QInterest:  "Swimming" 
Name:    Interest:`
.
As you can see, the converted buffer does not be saved as a const value, what about the problem?
Also, there are some differences between these two OS, what is the cause maybe?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are observing is undefined behavior.

The call to `toLatin1()` creates a temporary `QByteArray`, which is destroyed immediately after that line, since you do not store it. The pointer obtained by `data()` is left dangling and might or might not print something useful.

Correct version:

```
const QByteArray& latinName = name.toLatin1();
const char* strName = latinName.data();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the [`toLatin1`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toLatin1) function returns a [`QByteArray`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html) object, and by not saving this object it will be temporary and be destructed once the assignment have been done.

That means your pointer points to some data that no longer exists, and dereferencing it will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Oh, I see. Could I use "strcpy" to copy the buffer value of the QByteArray?
I have test it, it works.

Comment: @user3857893 Yes you could. But then you need to allocate memory, and not forget the string terminator. I also wonder *why* you need this pointer? If you just are going to pass it to a C function then it's okay to use temporary objects like you do (as long as you do e.g. `name.toLatin1().data()` for the *argument* expression).

Comment: You are right, because I have many places to use this value as a type of "const char *", so I save the value in a const variable.